# Kdenlive not uploading new fonts

Tags: fonts, kdenlive

I have downloaded new fonts to use on Kdenlive 21.12.2 . None of them seem to be uploading on Kdenlive.  The fonts appear on Libreoffice but not on Kdenlive. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

What can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the snap version of Kdenlive. Switching to the apt version should fix it.

Open a terminal and enter the following command.

```
sudo snap remove kdenlive && sudo apt install kdenlive
```